# Trying to use decorators to time some data and return it with type() method, but it wont call the function

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

im trying to use a decorator to automatize my code to time its execution with the time module. The execution should be only assigning a big value to a var... i got it right but in the end of the code i needed to print the type() of the data im using too, so i wanted to create a function to format this for me, printing the time of the execution and the data type next to it, but i would tell me that 'float' object is not callable... could someone help me out to try to automatize the code just a slightly more?

```
import time
#time counter for single args:
tspac(); line(57)
def timing_dec(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def timing(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.perf_counter()
        result = t2 - t1
        try:
            return (((result)*100_000))
        except AttributeError:
            print("not a .type arg")
            return ((result)*100_000)
    return timing

@timing_dec
def set_data(dat):
    dat   

@set_data           
def formatTimingProcess(x): 
    print(set_data(x), type(x))

a_data = ("abcde" * 10_000_00)
formatTimingProcess(a_data)
```

this should show:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\uiuiudy\Desktop\programacionesss\pythona\tutorsss\decorators.py", line 84, in <module>
    formatTimingProcess(a_data)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

i only got it right when i directly printed it

```
x = "abcde" * 10_000_00
print(set_data(x), type(x))
```